# UITableViewCell Separator line misalignment

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I set tableView.rowHeight to 57, one of the cells always have the wrong row height. What could be the reason? Also I've tried implementing the delegate method as well with no luck. [image]

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller just implement the following delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 57f;
}
```

Comment: is the delegate properlu setup? in the viewcontroller self.tableView.delegate =self;

Comment: yea, I'm using a tableviewController that has tableview datasource already connected I believe

Answer (score 0):

your custom cell height and heightForRowAtIndexPath returned height should be same.
suppose custom cell height is 65.and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 65f;
}
```